# Does accept() should modify address_len on failure?

Tags: sockets, posix, freebsd

In the following partial code:

```
addrlen = sizeof(addr);
accept(sk, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &addrlen);
```

If accept fails, is it possible for addrlen to be 0 or otherwise != sizeof(addr)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POSIX was not clear on this, and reportedly FreeBSD did set `*address_len` to 0 on some error conditions, although most systems leave it unchanged on error.  The next POSIX revision [will clarify](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=836) that `*address_len` shall not be modified on error.  At least until the next POSIX revision becomes ubiquitous, applications would be wise not to assume anything about the value of `*address_len` if an error is returned.

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't, but I seem to remember a recently fixed bug where that actually happened.

Comment: can you point out where in POSIX or the documentation that requirment lives?

Comment: @GoodPerson I'm not sure, to be honest, but see this commit log: http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=265896

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can rely on it, and I can't see any reason why you would want to either. The first thing you should examine is the return code, which is -1 on error, and only examine the address/address length on success.

Comment: What if I need to call this routine in a loop (perhaps it returned EINTR?)  Should I reset addr_len each time?

Comment: If there is success, the addrlen will be updated to reflect the proper value

Comment: Yes, you should reset it every time.